# JS switch case not working

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a switch case statement that doesn't work. I've checked the input, it's valid. If user is 1, it goes to default. If user is any number, it defaults. What's wrong here? I don't know javascript well at all.

```
switch (user) {
case 1:
    // stuff
    break;
case 2:
    // more stuff
    break;
default:
    // this gets called
    break;
}
```

Comment: What does the variable `user` contain? An `object` or an `int`?

Comment: That is why I prefer strong typing:)

Comment: Chris, try `switch(~~user)`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Make sure you are not mixing strings and integers.
Try:

```
switch (user) {
    case "1":
        // stuff
        break;
    case "2":
        // more stuff
        break;
    default:
        // this gets called
}
```

Comment: `default` not necessary `break`

Answer (score 12):

Problem is data type mismatch. cast type of **user** to integer.

Comment: How? I thought all you do in js is var

Answer (score 12):

Cast type of user variable to integer

```
 switch (+user) {   
    case 1: .. //
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Javascript is type-aware. So '1' is not the same as 1. In your case the "user" has to be numeric, not the string. You can cast it by just:

```
user = Number(user)
```